# How can I add clickable tags and category to WordPress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories

I would like to add clickable `Tags` and `Category` to my `WordPress` post template. I use a plugin for `PHP` display in WordPress post.

Here is my code:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name.' &nbsp;&nbsp; '; 
    }
}
```

But I would like to display clickable tags and category.
What `PHP` code I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_tag_link` to get the link of tag. Look at the following example:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
    echo '<a href="' . $tag_link . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; '; 
  }
}
```

Look at WordPress reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Showing categories:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';

    echo $category_link;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you know how to add category in simmilar way?

Comment: You can use `get_categories` function the same way and display as you did for tags and get the category link using `get_category_link`

Comment: It's possible to show only this post category? not all category?

Comment: Use `get_the_category` to get the list of categories associated with current post.